# rails - Delayed jobs without perform method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

After make a big class with many method, I want all of these method be called in a delayed jobs.

But the practice of the `Delayed::job`, is that you have to create a class with a `perform` method, like that :

```
class Me < Struct.new(:something)
   def perform
     puts "GO"
   end
end
```

and call it like :

```
 Delayed::Job.enqueue Me.new(1)
```

But the problem is that my class as already many method like this type

```
class NameHandler
  def self.init
    ap "TODO : Delayed jobs "
  end

  def self.action_one
    ...
  end

  def self.action_two
    ...
  end

etc.

end
```

and I want to call it like :

```
 Delayed::Job.enqueue NameHandler.action_one params...
```

Theres is an best practice for that ? Or I have to follow the classic Delayed::job way and lose many times ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [README](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#queuing-jobs) it has a number of ways:

```
Me.new.delay.action_one
```

or

```
class NameHandler
  handle_asynchronously :action_one  

  def action_one      
  end

  def self.action_one
    new.action_one
  end
end

NameHandler.action_one
```